# How do I use a Radio Button to vary the dropdown menu in a R Shiny App?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm very new to using Shiny apps but have managed to put together a dropdown menu for a list of TagIDs. However there are 3 types of Tag IDs that I would like to differentiate between. Two simple solutions are 1) just creating different tab items for each Tag ID type or 2) adding text in front of each TagID to delineate the type. What I would like to do is create a radio button for the 3 types of tags that modifies the list of TagIDs present within the dropdown menu. Any idea on how to do this "nested" dropdown menu within a radio button?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what you're looking for, but this might be helpful. In the demo below, you can use `updateSelectInput` in an `observe` block. When a change is made with the radio buttons (e.g., when a "type" is selected), then the `selectInput` choices for tagIDs are updated based on the type selected.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

df <- data.frame(
  type = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
  tagID = 1:6
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Menu"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    radioButtons("types", "Type", unique(df$type)),
    selectInput("tagIDs", "TagID", NULL)
  ),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(
      session, "tagIDs", "TagID",
      choices = df[df$type == input$types, "tagID"]
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```